# How to find paragraph closest to the top of the viewer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying use javascript to identify the paragraph element that is closest to the top of the viewing area at the time that the function was fired.

I tried to use: http://gilmoreorless.github.io/jquery-nearest/

with the following code:

```
var $paragraphs = $('p.plaoulparagraph');
console.log($paragraphs.nearest({y: 0, x: 0}));
```

But this always gives me the first paragraph no matter what is visible in the viewport.

I think the reason this is not working is that according to the documentation the coordinates refer to the page, not the viewing area.

> pointObject is an object with x and y (numeric) properties that define
>   a point on the page (relative to the top left corner of the page, not
>   the screen).

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this plugin but the top of viewport and `$(window).scrollTop()` are the same so try:

```
$paragraphs.nearest({y: $(window).scrollTop(), x: 0});
```

Comment: thanks that's helpful. Also, there should be a `,` after scrollTop() instead of a `:` That was my mistake in the original post.

Comment: glad it helped...sorry about typo ...i work with objects daily, my bad